# What's the difference between 「か嫌いだとか」 and 「か嫌いだったり」

Tags: grammar

> 人を第一印象で好き**だとか**嫌い**だとか**言うのはやめなさい。

Can I say this like:

> 人を第一印象で好き**だったり**嫌い**だったりと**言うのはやめなさい。

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 2):

～たりと言う is unnatural. ～たりする is natural. For example, 彼女は、彼のことを好きになったり嫌いになったりする. So your second example is unnatural. 人を第一印象で好きになったり嫌いになったりするのはやめなさい is more natural.